# Using the default audio ouput for AVAudioEngine in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a basic iOS application that let me record audio and then play it back in different speeds and pitches.

I'm using `AVAudioPlayer` to play the recorded audio either slower or faster and it works as expected. The sound is played back in my headphones.

I'm using `AVAudioEngine` to play the recorded audio in a different pitch and it works except that the audio is played back on my Thunderbolt display speakers, not my headphones.

I've been going through the documentation in order to understand this behavior but come up short. In my view controller in the method, `viewDidLoad`, I've setup the audio session as follows:

```
 let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
 session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &error)
 session.setActive(true, error: &error)
```

and further down, I've defined a function that triggers the sound that utilizes the audio engine as follows:

```
let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
audioEngine.attachNode(playerNode)

let changePitchNode = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
changePitchNode.pitch = 1000
audioEngine.attachNode(changePitchNode)

audioEngine.connect(playerNode, to: changePitchNode, format: audioFile.processingFormat)
audioEngine.connect(changePitchNode, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: audioFile.processingFormat)

playerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
audioEngine.startAndReturnError(nil)
playerNode.play()
```

`audioEngine` and `audioFile` are globally declared in the class. The whole project can be found at https://github.com/KevinSjoberg/pitch-perfect.

Can anyone shed some light to why it persists on playing the sound on my monitor speaker instead of my headphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. The reason for this happening was that I was using the Thunderbolt Display microphone to record my voice. For some unknown reason this makes the `AVAudioEngine` use the monitor speakers instead. By switching the input source to the microphone of my MBP made everything work as expected.

I'm only guessing, but it does sound like a bug and so I've submitted a report to Apple.